# Extract the class label from glass.data?

Tags: dataset, label, extract

I am facing a problem in extracting the class label. May anyone help me please !

By using Jupyter notebook:

1. load data from this link:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/glass.data

2. Write code to remove the first attribute (which is a unique ID), get the remaining attributes as reals, and extract the class label (which is the last element in each line of glass.data).